# Mapbox Examples - how to begin?

Tags: android, sdk, mapbox

I'd like to begin loading mapbox examples in AndroidStudio. I followed guides, but I'm struggling with dependencies problems.
Can someone help me, please?
I downloaded examples from github and loaded it in my AndroidStudio.
I follow all explanations, dependencies.... repositories... ecc

I syncronized Gradle and it is ok.

I Cleared Cache and.. nothings!

But example don't works !

for example in this: `import com.mapbox.mapboxandroiddemo.R;` I have this error: error: cannot find symbol class R

Naturally I followed this guide `https://docs.mapbox.com/help/tutorials/first-steps-android-sdk/`

Is there any example that simply I can download and works?
Help me please. Thank you very mutch.

Comment: for example in this:
```import com.mapbox.mapboxandroiddemo.R;``` I have this error: error: cannot find symbol class R

Answer (score 0):

Try swapping `import com.mapbox.mapboxandroiddemo.R` with your app'spackage name. You can find the app's package in the manifest file

`import PACKAGE_NAME.R`